# How to draw triangle in plane using Peaucellier inversor?

Tags: geometry

All of us in real life have a deal with some mechanisms which execute some motion. Few days ago I meet the article *How to draw a straight line* using Peaucellier inersor ([example of this mechanism).](http://jeanlouis.blanchard.pagesperso-orange.fr)

After all I thought that it's easy to construct any polyhedron using some mechanisms like this, but what about one mechanism (*one* means there is no parts , consists of other inversors).

My question is : is it possible to construct another geometry body, for example triangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the very answer is in the [Roberts'curve linkage](http://jeanlouis.blanchard.pagesperso-orange.fr/english_swf/roberts_curve.html) with all beams of equal size, is the answer for a triangle.

Comment: But it draws approximate triangle.

Comment: I mean: suppose we have $f(x,y) = 0$, which means triangle.
Robert's curve build something else.

Comment: No i think with all links with the same length $l$, separated by $2l$, it draws a perfect equilateral triangle.